# Most frequent element in an array

Tags: arrays

Given all numbers are in the range 0 to n-1 where n is the length of the array.
How to solve this in linear time and constant space?

Comment: *all numbers are in the range 0 to n-1* and *are positive* combines to *all numbers are in the range 1 to n-1*, or are those two separate questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse given array as a counter for numbers. Just iterate through the array and increment corresponding counter. The only trick is to increment each time by n, not by one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    arr[arr[i]%n] += n;
}
```

After this loop element arr[i] will be changed to arr[i]+n*count[i], where arr[i]<n. So this way the most frequent element is the one with the greatest value. In order to restore the original value, just take arr[i]%n.

Comment: why do we need the % if all the elements are  lesser than n-1?

Comment: It's because while you're iterating, you incrementing values to something bigger than n. For example, if n=3 and you have array 2,2,2, then after first iteration you'd have array 2,2,5; after second iteration 2,2,8; and after last iteration you have to get 2,2,11. This is possible only if you take a remainder for getting array element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to achieve this. But it is not O(n) as you required, it is O(n^2). Hope this help

```
function getPopularElement(array) {
  var count = 1, tempCount;
  var popular = array[0];
  var temp = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < (array.length - 1); i++) {
    temp = array[i];
    tempCount = 0;

    for (var j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (temp == array[j]) {
        tempCount++;
      }
    }

    if (tempCount > count) {
      popular = temp;
      count = tempCount;
    }
  }

  return popular;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heller's solution is actually similar to this: the idea is to go through the array and for each element increase a counter at that number's position in the array. Generally there's another element at that position (where Heller is keeping the information by counting in step sizes of `n`) but **we can resolve those elements recursively and in-place**. This is a linear process done at most once per element, since there can be no longer chains (trying to increase a count at a position, finding a new element) than the length of the whole array (i.e. a single permutation cycle) and once an element is processed, it can be skipped in the main loop making it `O(n)` overall. **The trick is to decrease the counter**:

```
//input: arr
//output: most frequent element, number of occurrences
n <- arr.length
for i = 0..n-1
    val <- arr[i]
    if val < 0
        // this element has already been processed
        continue
    // set counter at i to zero (-1)
    arr[i] <- -1
    // resolve the chain
    do
        idx <- val
        val <- arr[idx]
        if val < 0
            // arrived at a counter, end of chain
            // increase the counter by one (-1)
            arr[idx] <- arr[idx] - 1
            break
        }
        // otherwise continue the chain with val
        // and initialise the counter at idx to one (-2)
        arr[idx] <- -2

// find the most common element
idx <- 0
for i = 1..n-1
    // smaller value means larger counter
    if arr[i] < arr[idx]
        idx <- i

// [the most frequent element, number of occurrences]
output [idx, -(arr[idx] + 1)] // arr[i] = -1 - #occurrences
```

This solution also deals nicely with very large arrays where the biggest possible counter in Heller's solution (`n*n-1`) overflows the underlying integer (for 32bit integers that's arrays longer than 65535 elements!)

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose the array is as follows:

```
int arr[] = {10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 20, 20,40,40,50,15,15,15};

int max =0;
int result = 0;
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( map.containsKey(arr[i])) 
        map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) +1);
    else
        map.put(arr[i], 1);
    int key = map.keySet().iterator().next();
    if (map.get(key) > max) {
        max = map.get(key) ;
        result = key;
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

### Explanation :

In the above code I have taken HashMap to store the elements in keys and the repetition of the elements as values.
We have initialized variable max = 0 ( max is the maximum count of repeated element)
While iterating over elements We are also getting the max count of keys.

The result variable returns the keys with the mostly repeated.